# Смена узла при раскрытии дерева

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Есть такой код

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $('.expand').click(function() {
    $('.info', this).toggle();
  });
});
```

```css
.expand {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.expand:before {
  content: '+';
  margin-right: 1ex;
}

.info {
  display: none;
  margin-left: 2ex;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="expand">Expand
  <div class="info">Info</div>
</div>
```

Вопрос: как бы минимальными усилиями при раскрытии узла менять начальный `+` на `-`?

Comment: кстати библиотека : https://www.jstree.com/demo/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $('.expand').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('opened');
  });
});
```

```css
.expand {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.expand:before {
  content: '+';
  margin-right: 1ex;
}

.expand.opened:before {
  content: '-';
  margin-right: 1.5ex;
}

.info {
  display: none;
  margin-left: 2ex;
}

.opened .info {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="expand">Expand
  <div class="info">Info</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо. Вчера лег спать и перед сном сам пришел к такому же коду. Единственная ремарка - если вместо класса `opened` использовать `closed`, то css получается немного компактнее

Comment: да, классы можно как угодно назвать

Comment: Дело не в названии. У `closed` логика будет инверсная

Answer (score 1):

Костыльный вариант на `HTML`+`CSS`:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: Arial;
}

a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}

/*BEGIN | MAIN*/
.list {
  position: relative;
  list-style-type: none;
  display: none;
  margin-left: 0.4rem;
}

.collapse {
  margin: 0.5rem 1.2rem;
  position: relative;
}

label {
  cursor: pointer;
  user-select: none;
  font-size: 1.5em;
}

label::before {
  content: "+";
  color: gray;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: -1rem;
}

#toggle {
  display: none;
}

#toggle:checked~.list {
  display: block;
}

#toggle:checked~label::before {
  content: "-";
}
/*END | MAIN*/
```

```html
<div class="collapse">
  <input type="checkbox" id="toggle">
  <label for="toggle">Expand</label>
  <ul class="list">
    <li><a href="#">first</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">second</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">third</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Конечно сложно назвать решением, но как минимум без `JS`:D

Comment: Нормальное решение, учитывая его принципиально отличие от предидущих

Comment: Мне не пригодится, но идея красивая

Answer (score 0):

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $('.expand').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('closed');
  });
});
```

```css
.expand {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.expand:before {
  content: '\2013';
  margin-right: 1ex;
}

.closed.expand:before {
  content: '+';
}

.info {
  margin-left: 2ex;
}

.closed .info {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="expand closed">Expand
  <div class="info">Info</div>
</div>
```